# Rough in plumbing for double vanity…

Tags: plumbing

Can someone tell me if the drain/vent set up for a double vanity in the image is good (up to code)? Yes, it is a little convoluted, but extremely limited to how the pipe can be run:

1. Can’t go up… window in the way.
2. Can’t go across the wall through studs.

So has to stay between studs and run under the floor.

Thanks for any help!

[image: bow vents for double vanity]

Comment: As drawn, the left hand sink doesn't actually have a vent. I'm not sure that'll work.

Comment: It's taking a shot at **Island venting** (both) with the left one also **wet-venting** the island vent. I'm dubious at best, and it will depend on the applicable code for the area as to whether it passes, so we'd need to know what that is. Please [edit] to add that information, as codes do differ. As for the "can'ts" sometimes those lead to "can't put that sink here" or "can learn to live with a pipe chase if you really want a sink here"